# 344. Reverse String LeetCode

Tags: java, arrays

I've got this code that runs in my IDE, Intellij but it will not run in LeetCode. Am I misunderstanding the question?

> Write a function that reverses a string. The input string is given as an array of characters char[].

> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

> You may assume all the characters consist of printable ascii characters.

```
class Solution {
public void reverseString(char[] s) {
    int arrayLength = s.length - 1;
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            int temp = s.length - i - 1;
            if (i != arrayLength) {
                System.out.printf("\"%s\",", s[temp]);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("\"%s\"", s[temp]);
            }
        }
        System.out.print("]");
}
```

}

Comment: Brian, you need to modify the input array. Do an inplace resolution of the problem basically.

Comment: Okay, if I understand correctly, I need to reprint the array in reverse by swapping the indexes?

Comment: No not print, only swap indexes

Comment: Reading forward in pseudocode: `(i=0 .. i=n)` prints arr[0], arr[1], .., arr[n].
Reading backward in pseudocode: `(i=n .. i=0)` prints arr[n], .., arr[1], arr[0].
Where `n = length-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question does not actually require you to print the string.

**char[] s**
is an object and simply modify its content to be reversed. [inplace]

Simply swap the contents of the char array using indices. It will be automatically recognized and be tested upon.

Comment: One doesn't need to swap the elements. Iterating and printing in reverse would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved this task.
The meaning of the task is you can't allocate new objects you should use the original array.

Comment: Don't give the answer please